# How to access YouTube transcriptions?

Tags: youtube

Suddenly I realized, that I have no transcription to any YT-video. Tested with multiple browsers (Chrome, FF, Edge, on desktop, mobile and in the mobile app), with login and incognito, mobile and desktop, with CC off and on. Under three-point menu I see only *report*. All browsers are up to date, no adblockers, cookies deleted.

I've seen at reddit such threads around a year ago - but they were explained as temporary bugs. What I experience looks like YT removed the option "Show transcript" completely.

Does somebody see the same? Is there a way to turn transcripts on again? Are there workarounds to access transcripts directly with a link?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on mobile view, you can't access the transcript. Your browser might let you "request desktop site" to switch, however.

In desktop view, it's at the end of the description (make sure it's expanded):

[image: "Show transcript"]